# How can I fix this black box?

Tags: themes

After upgradinng to 15.04 today, something is wrong with the Adwaita theme and I have boxes like this one all over the place:

[image]

Oddly, in the screenshot, it's a big white box, but on my system it shows up as a big black box (if I took a picture of my screen with a camera, the box that's white above would be black!)

Switching away from the Adwaita theme seems to fix the issue, but I have been using Adwaita for a long time and don't want to use another theme.

I reinstalled Adwaita:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall adwaita*
```

But that didn't help either.

Any ideas how to get the theme fixed?

EDIT: Here's another example, but it's actually black in this image:

[image]

Comment: It looks almost like, since there are no elements there, it's just not filling in the background. Weird.

Comment: I'm guessing you have a black background? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-tweak-tool/+bug/1304092

Comment: Yeah, that sounds about right. Everything is set to Adwaita, btw.

Comment: @Mateo, no, but that's an interesting bug, for sure. This affects other apps too. I'll put up another screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug with the overlay-scrollbar package. I fixed it with

```
sudo apt-get remove overlay-scrollbar
```

Comment: Woah! Is there a bug report?

Comment: Yes, it was on a similar question I used to fix this problem. However, I am on mobile and don't remember the link.